# C# HttpClient and Windows Authentication: Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.7.1

I'm using the native C# HTTP client with a handler to process Windows Authentication and I'm having `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials })
{
    bool disposeHandler = true; //Setting true or false does not fix the problem
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, disposeHandler))
    {
        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello")))
        {
            // Commenting/uncommenting the line below does not fix the problem
            // httpRequestMessage.Headers.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");

            using (var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://SomeUrl", content)) // This line throws an ObjectDisposedException
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some new investigations, I think/fear there it is a **Microsoft bug in HttpClientHandler (or HttpClient)**:

If instead of using the PostAsync method I use the SendAsync method, I can compose my request with more options and especially change the **HTTP version** from **1.1** (by default) to **1.0**. Then in this case the real exception was revealed (and it was not anymore hidden/overridden by the ObjectDisposedException exception). For your information, my real exception was the following:

*--> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.*

*--> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect*

(Still for your information, this exception was due to a bad configuration of an SPN of a user in the Active Directory)

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials })
{
    bool disposeHandler = true; //Setting true or false does not fix the problem
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, disposeHandler))
    {
        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello")))
        {
            // Commenting/uncommenting the line below does not fix the problem
            // httpRequestMessage.Headers.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://SomeUrl")
            {
                Content = content,
                Version = HttpVersion.Version10
            };

            using (var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)) // This line still throws but with the real exception (and not the ObjectDisposedException)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beware: downgrading the HTTP version is just a hack to get the real exception message, HTTP 1.0 is getting very old.

Any experts analysis would be really appreciated. Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting PreAuthenticate = true, it will add the authorization header with the AD/User token, you should get a 401 followed by a second request, with the header, suggest you view it in fiddler.

```
httpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Comment: First thank you for your reply, unfortunately this didn't fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You're disposing of your `HttpResponseMessage` before it's had a chance to be evaluated.  Try this instead.

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = null;
using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello")))
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://SomeUrl")
    {
        Content = content,
        Version = HttpVersion.Version10
    };

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, disposeHandler))
    {
        httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm no, I'm disposing response after